# Why multiple sub-instance are running in electron?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am new to Electron and sorry if i am asking a very basic question.

### Current Scenario

I am running a new electron app though the command

```
npm run start
```

and on running it shows multiple sub-instance of electron that are running.
[image]

### Current Code

App.jsx

[image]

index.js

[image]

### Output

[image]

### Question

I want to know why are these multiple instances running? 
Can they be removed to reduce overall memory consumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron is based on Chromium for HTML rendering and JavaScript execution. If you open up Chrome's (or Chromium's) task manager by right clicking the tab bar and selecting "Task Manager", you will see that Chrome spawns a separate process for each tab, one for the basic browser functions and a "GPU process", which handles graphic rendering on your hardware (or software).

Electron does the same: It spawns one base process, one for your page, one for rendering your page and the last one, "React App", for the React stuff of your application. Google uses this concept to increase Chrome's/Chromium's overall performance by splitting different tasks to different processes which are independent and thus won't block each other.

This is the way Chrome/Chromium works and I believe that there would be a great benefit from cutting the number of processes (if any). However, it seems that there is no way to tell Electron to just run on one single process.